# logstash metadata not passed to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to follow the example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7

But the index name set by 30-elasticsearch-output.conf is not being resolved. In the example 30-elasticsearch-output.conf file:

```
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

In my case, the result elasticsearch index name is:

```
"%{[@metadata][beat]}-2016.09.07"
```

Only the date portion of the index name is set correctly.
What is responsible for setting the metadata value? I must have missed something in following the example.

This is related to a question asked earlier: [ELK not passing metadata from filebeat into logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384654/elk-not-passing-metadata-from-filebeat-into-logstash)

Comment: Have you seen this page : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.3/faq.html#metadata-missing? Apparently metadata is remove by the logstash outputs, so _maybe_ the metadata is already removed when it tries to retrieve the value for the index name

Comment: News here? ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create index like this

```
 index => "%{[beat][name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

This would work definitely.